# What causes transition not to work in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I wrote CSS. This works fine for blur.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".transition").classList.toggle("blur");
})
```

```css
.transition {
  transition: 5s;
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="transition">
  TEXT
</div>
```

However, this will not work with React.js and Styled Components. I want to realize transition by filter without using add-on. Why doesn't this work, and how does it work?

- [CodeSandBox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-elion-4bzc2)

```js
const Button = styled.button``;
let ToggleBlurText = styled.div`
  transition: "5s"
`;

function App() {
  const [blur, setBlur] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    ToggleBlurText = styled.div`
      filter: blur(${blur ? "0px" : "5px"});
      transition: "5s"
    `;
  }, [blur]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ToggleBlurText>
        <h2>TEXT</h2>
      </ToggleBlurText>
      <Button onClick={() => setBlur(!blur)}>button</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approach will not work. React probably won't re-render the `ToggleBlurText` component and the styles inside the effect will not be applied.

Instead, you can create a styled component and toggle a css class that changes the blur depending on your state.

```
const Button = styled.button``;
const ToggleBlurText = styled.div`
  transition: 5s;
  filter: blur(0px);

  &.blur {
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
`;

function App() {
  const [blur, setBlur] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ToggleBlurText className={blur ? 'blur' : ''}>
        <h2>TEXT</h2>
      </ToggleBlurText>
      <Button onClick={() => setBlur(prev => !prev)}>button</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also fixed a typo in your styled component css and also changed the onClick handler slightly.

Comment: onClick worked by rewrite to [`() => setBlur(!blur)`](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-beaver-4ewt6). Does `prev` in the answer work? :

Comment: `prev` is a reference to the *previous* state. Although mostly just a semantic difference, I always recommend using the old reference whenever the new value of a state depends on the previous value. Since you are toggling from false to true and vice-versa, you have a state dependency, which is why I use that syntax here.

Comment: Thank you! I understood the meaning of the code. Are there any SO related topics about the cause of this issue? Checking with the developer tools, it seems that `ToggleBlurText` has been re-rendered and CSS has been applied.

Comment: (If I should post as another question, I will it.

Comment: @stackdestroy I don't think it is an "issue" really. It's an odd practice and you shouldn't do it that way.